# Find choice of parameter such that a probability bound (a power function multiply an exponential function) decay exponentially with $n$

Tags: probability, analysis

Let $\beta:=\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\log n}}$, consider

$\Big (\text{Ceiling of}{\frac{\pi}{2\epsilon}}\Big)^n \cdot \exp\Big({-\frac{n-1}{\beta^2}}\Big)$

Is it possible to find $\epsilon>0$, such that the expression decays exponentially with $n$, i.e. $\sim O(e^{-cn})$?

Update:

By numerical plotting, I plot the function by choosing different $\epsilon<\pi/2$, it seems the function always increasing. Is there any way to prove it?

Comment: Did you try combining into a single exponential? I feel like that would probably help

Comment: Are you restricting the value of $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes. The value of $\beta$ is given as a function of $n$, so there is only $\epsilon$ left.

Comment: The base of the first factor is greater than one, the second factor is essentially $1/n^2$, so it's clear that the expression is diverging for increasing $n$. As for the follow-up question: Yes, it's possible. Consider your expression with $n$ replaced by $x\in[1,\infty)$ and take the derivative.